# Best way to process multiple HTTP async requests in the background and return responses individually

Tags: iphone, ios, network-programming, httpwebrequest, nsurlconnection

I basically have one class that processes requests composing this framework, https://github.com/ivasic/RESTframework. I want to be able to execute requests requests and return responses individually to the caller. As it stands if I have more than two request, the result of the second one domes not come through, it seems they all happen at the same time.

What would be a solution to this?

Comment: you should look at AFNetworking and the HTTPClient class.  Makes the whole rest thing very easy.

Comment: @John, I looked at AFNetworking and the AFHTTPClient, you  can use this to make requests, but I am looking for some queuing mechanism that will allow me to perform multiple and be able to send data from one request to another inline sort of.

Comment: so you want the data from one request to goto another request?

Comment: Yep, and the caller to be able to so whatever they want with the response thereof.

Comment: i don't think you will get this for free.  You will have to just execute the first request, and in the response handler, kick off the second  request. Then in the second response handler send the data back to the caller.

Comment: @John, yes, that's exactly what I resorted to, I realized it's not necessarily possible to do it individually like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the caller pass a block to your "one class that handles requests."  This caller block can then do anything with the response.

```
// inside the caller class.
OneClassThatHandlesRequests *ws = [OneClassThatHandlesRequest sharedInstance];
[ws getFromURL: @"http://webservice.com/people/jack" completionBlock: ^(URLRequest *request , URLHTTPResponse *response, NSData *data) {
        // make sure we we got a 200 code back.
        // change the data into JSON if I'm getting JSON back.
        }];
```

Now your OneClassThatHandlesRequests knows how to pass back the information to the call without the OneClassThatHandlesRequests needing to know anything about the called.

You could also use delegate pattern, but blocks for this case makes more sense to me

Comment: Yep, I am using this technique, with delegate it would not make sense as I want to receive a one time response instead or received different type of responses.